# how to display a number on text view which was stored in variable

Tags: iphone, uitextview

i want to display a number assigned to variable on text view ...
how to show number on text view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
myTextView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", yourNumberVariable]
```

You should adjust "%d" to whatever the type of the variable is.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added that UITextView to the main view? Something like

```
[self.view addSubview:myTextView];
[myTextView setText:@"Hello World"];
```

or

```
// this will "convert" from integer to string
[myTextView setText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", myNumber]
```

Comment: yes,i want to know how to display a number stored in a variable to textview

Comment: I have modified my answer to include more info